# Returning HTML as respond in deno

Tags: deno

With the below simple [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) code at [Deno](https://deno.land/) runtime:

```js
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@v0.24.0/http/server.ts"

async function main() {
    const body = new TextEncoder().encode("Hello World\n");
    let port = 8000
    const s = serve({ port: port });
    console.log(`Server had been started at:
    http://localhost:${port}/`);
    for await (const req of s) {
      req.respond({ body });
    }
};

main()
```

Which is executed by running:

```sh
D:\repos\deno>deno --allow-net main.ts
Compile file:///D:/repos/deno/main.ts
Server had been started at:
    http://localhost:8000/
```

is displaying a `Hello World` at the browser.

Is there a way to display an HTML element instead of text, something like displaying `<h1>` or `<button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add html inside your string like this

```
const body = new TextEncoder().encode("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
```

If you want multiple html element, you can use template literal / template string like this

```
const body = new TextEncoder().encode(`
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
        <h1>Ryan Dahl From Future</h1>
        <p>Do you need another js runtime ?</p>
    </div>
`);
```

Answer (score 3):

just add your html inside your string

example

```
const body = new TextEncoder().encode("<h1>Hello World</h1>\n");
```

Comment: Thanks, can you help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59558678/2441637