# How can I add eventListner and attribute to HTML element in Deno

Tags: deno

I've the below code with [Deno](https://deno.land/) runtime, which is displating a button at the website:

1. How can I change the attributes of this button
2. How can I add eventListner for this button

```js
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@v0.24.0/http/server.ts"

async function main() {
    const body = new TextEncoder().encode(`<button>click me</button>\n`);
    const s = serve({ port: 8000 });
    console.log(`Server had been started at: http://localhost:8000/`);
    for await (const req of s) {
      req.respond({ body });
    }
};

main()
```

Comment: I suggest tagging this question as `html` or `DOM` instead of `deno`. Deno is just for serving the site, but otherwise all the DOM operations are related to the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By replacing

```
<button>click me</button>\n
```

with

`<button id='button' onclick="document.getElementById('button').innerHTML='wow I changed'">click me</button>\n`

or another example where you add the eventListener separately

```
`<button id='button'>click me</button><script>document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',function(){document.getElementById('button').innerHTML='wow I changed';});</script>\n`
```